# Determining constants $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ approximate second derivate of finite difference

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

given that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^4$, how can I find $a,b,c,d$ such that for a fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$$e_h:=\Bigg |\frac{au(x)+bu(x+h)+cu(x+2h)+du(x+3h)}{h^2}-u''(x)\Bigg |=O(h^2)$$

I've tried to use the MVT and talyor expansion of $u(x+h),u(x+2h), u(x+3h)$, but I don't know how I am supposed to show that it is equal to $O(h^2)$?

**what I tried**

So I found the taylor up to order $4$ to get a system of equations for $a,b,c,d$. But to show that it is $O(h^2)$ do I try to construct a $u_h$, since $u_h-u=O(h^\alpha)$ so there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $$|u_h-u|\leq ch^\alpha$$

Is this on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to think of this: say you have $n$ given sample points some $h$-scaled distance away from a fixed point $x$ written as $x + r_ih$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Our goal is to find an approximation of $u^{(k)}(x)$ for some $k \geq 0$ by using a linear combination of the form $\sum_{i=1}^na_iu(x+ r_ih)$; we will need to determine the coefficients $a_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and the order of the approximation. Like you said we will use the Taylor expansion to get:
$$ u(x+ r_ih) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{r_i^jh^j}{j!}u^{(j)}(x) $$
$$\implies u^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^na_iu(x+ r_ih) = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{r_i^jh^j}{j!}u^{(j)}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{h^j}{j!}\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^ja_i\right)u^{(j)}(x) $$
By comparing coefficients on both sides, this means that we need $\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^ja_i = 0$ for $j \neq k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^ka_i = \frac{k!}{h^k}$, or writing $R$ as the Vandermonde matrix with entries $r_{ij}  := r_j^i$ this is the linear system $R^T\vec a = \vec b$ where $\vec a$ is the vector of $a_i$ coefficients and $\vec b$ is the vector with all zeros except $\frac{k!}{h^k}$ in the $k+1$ spot. In order for this to be invertible we need $R$ to be square, and since there are $n$ columns, the number of rows is also $n$ so we need $k+1 \leq n$ in order to solve. Furthermore, since $r_i$ and $k$ are fixed, $\sum_{i=1}^nr_i^ka_i = \frac{k!}{h^k}$ tells us that the $a_i$ scale like $h^{-k}$ and so the order of our resultant approximation is $n-k$.

Now to take this back to your problem, we essentially need to solve the matrix equation $$ \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 4 & 9 \\ 0 & 1 & 8 & 27
  \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d
  \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{2}{h^2} \\ 0
  \end{matrix}\right) $$
which I will leave for you to complete.